# Make the menu items of a menu overflow icon at the centre of screen

Tags: android

I want to show the drop down items upon clicking the menu overflow icon at the action bar of my app, at the center of the device screen.

Here is the menu overflow icon

[image]

Here is the menu items on clicking the icon

[image]

I want those items to be shown at the center of the screen. How to go about doing that?

Comment: Why on earth you want to do that ....

Comment: I was just curious, wanted to know how to do that @JozefDochan :)

Comment: Instead you can use a spinner.

Comment: well use a [Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) instead.